# Which of these statements are always true?

Tags: logic

this problem has been asked on mathexchange already, but i fail to understand why only the second option is always true:

1.$((\forall x(P(x) \lor Q(x)))) \implies ((\forall xP(x)) \lor (\forall xQ(x)))$

2.$(\forall x(P(x) \implies Q(x))) \implies ((\forall xP(x)) \implies (\forall xQ(x)))$

3.$(\forall x(P(x)) \implies \forall x(Q(x))) \implies (\forall x(P(x) \implies Q(x)))$

4.$(\forall x(P(x)) \iff (\forall x(Q(x)))) \implies (\forall x(P(x) \iff Q(x)))$

To make the formulas easier to read, because each predicate has the same subject $(x)$, let $P(x) = A$ and $Q(x) = B$. Because in each formula the predicates are expressed in such a way that only universal quantifiers are used, though I'm not sure, my guess is they can be discarded (by mentally 'factoring out' to the beginnings of the expressions). In that case I get the following:

1. $(((A \lor B))) \implies ((A) \lor (B)) = \lnot (A \lor B) \lor (A \lor B) = (\lnot A \lor \lnot B) \lor (A \lor B) = (A \land B) \lor (A \lor B)$

this is not tautology.

2. $((A \implies B)) \implies ((A) \implies (B)) = \lnot (\lnot A \lor B) \lor (\lnot A \lor B) = (A \lor \lnot B) \lor (\lnot A \lor B)$

this is tautology.

3. $((A) \implies (B)) \implies ((A \implies B)) = \lnot (\lnot (A) \lor (B)) \lor ((\lnot A \lor B)) = \lnot (\lnot A \lor B) \lor (\lnot A \lor B) = (A \lor \lnot B) \lor (\lnot A \lor B)$

this is tautology.

4. $((A) \iff ((B))) \implies ((A \iff B))$

this is tautology (implicated identity).

Comment: The formulas as they appear now are not very readable, try typing them out in LaTex next time. Here is a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

On a separate note, I am not too sure if abbreviating them into A and B would work; if that's the case, propositional logic would be just as strong as first order logic (I suspect?) - but I could be wrong. That may be one reason why the abbreviation seems to make some of them tautological when they are not supposed to.

Comment: If you translate them into propositional logic, you cannot understand them. For the first one, consider e.g.: "Every natural number is either Even or Odd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your procedure to “factorise” out quantifiers from a formula does change its meaning. [For example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication), assuming a non-empty domain of discourse,
$$\bigg(\forall x \big[\,P(x)\to Q(x)\,\big]\bigg) \kern.8em\not\kern-.8em\iff \bigg(\forall x P(x)\to\forall x Q(x)\bigg) \\ \iff \bigg(\forall y \exists x \big[\,P(x)\to Q(y)\,\big] \bigg) \\ \iff \bigg(\exists x \forall y \big[\,P(x)\to Q(y)\,\big] \bigg).$$

Comment: I though the following is correct: $\forall x(P(x)) \implies \forall x(Q(x)) =\lnot (\forall x(P(x))) \lor \forall x(Q(x)) =  \forall x(\lnot P(x)) \lor \forall x(Q(x)) = \forall x(\lnot P(x) \lor Q(x)) = \forall x(P(x) \implies Q(x))$

Is there an algebraic way of solving this problem, because I usually prefer those.

Comment: [This](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(%E2%88%80x(P(x))%20%E2%86%94%20%E2%88%80x(Q(x)))%20%E2%86%94%20((%E2%88%80x(P(x))%20%E2%86%92%E2%88%80x(Q(x)))%20%E2%88%A7%20(%E2%88%80x(Q(x))%20%E2%86%92%E2%88%80x(P(x))))) is what I meant, thanks Ryan for suggesting this site.

Comment: @autodidact The second and third equivalences in your above comment are incorrect (in each case, the link that I provided explains why). [This](https://tinyurl.com/52es9y3w) engine is a quick way to check whether the compound formulae $A$ and $B$ are equivalent: just type in $(A)\leftrightarrow(B)$. Incidentally, $\leftrightarrow, \to,$ and $=$ (material biconditional, material conditional, and equality, respectively) are all symbols in first-order arithmetic, whereas $\iff$ and $\implies$ (equivalence and implication) are *meta*logical symbols.....

Comment: ..... Although notations differ among texts, $=$ is never used to mean logical equivalence.  Finally, all this is quite a lot to digest, so give yourself time and take it easy.

Answer (score 0):

When you "factor out" the quantifier, you are applying something like a "law of distribution", which however does not exist for this.

To show you why for example equation 1) is not true, I'll let the domain over which $x$ varies be the positive integers, and $P(x)$ means "$x$ is the square of an integer" and $Q(x)$ means "x is not the square of an integer".

Then

$$\forall x (P(x) \lor Q(x))$$

means "for all positive integers $x$, $x$ is the square of an integer or not the square of an integer", which is true: Any positive integer is either a square or not.

However, $(\forall x P(x)) \lor (\forall x Q(x))$ means "all positive integers are squares of integers or all positive square integers are not squares of integers", which is wrong: It's an "or"-Statement, and both parts are false, as some positve integers are not squares (so $\forall x P(x)$ is false) and some positve integers are squares (so $\forall x Q(x)$ is false).